# jquery selector for container and all child elements except specified

Tags: jquery

I have a webform that consists of a search box and a table that is populated from the search. What I have happening is if you click anywhere on the table, your focus goes back to the search box to allow for rapid interaction.

I want to prevent this behavior on a few elements like the selects contained in the table. I would like to do so by adding a class so I can later change what ignores the focus change.

I think the issue is that my selector is looking for an element with the boxx class and without the noboxx class, but the child elements don't have the boxx class themselves but I can't seem to construct the selector I need.

```js
$('.boxx > *:not(.noboxx)').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#searchtext').focus().select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <input type='text' id='searchtext' />
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-10 boxx'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Important text</td>
        <td><button type="button">clicker</button></td>
        <td>
          <select class='noboxx'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>               </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with event propagation I believe.
Try this instead. It appears to me that this does what you are looking for.

```js
$('#theOuter').on('click', '.boxx .noboxx', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#theOuter').on('click', '.boxx *:not(.noboxx)', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#searchtext').focus().select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-2'>
        <input type='text' id='searchtext' />
    </div>
    <div id="theOuter">
        <div class='col-md-10 boxx'>
            <table id="theTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Important text</td>
                <td><button type="button">clicker</button></td>
                <td>
                    <select class='noboxx'>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="noboxx" style="border: 1px solid red; cursor: pointer">
                    stuff
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid blue; cursor: pointer">
                    more stuff
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is it auto closes the select and does not allow a selection to be made

Comment: This seems to work but only for elements that exist at load. I wrapped this into a function that applies the listener to controls after they are created as I couldn't figure out how to crate the selectors in a document.on(click, selector, funciton) setup.

Comment: The way to handle elements created later is to use a delegated event. I'll put an example in. It does require something above the elements in question to key on. I'll put an ID in the table so you can see what I mean.

Comment: adding theOuter broke the page css, but I changed theOuter to $(document) and it works just fine. Thank you for your help today. I was ready to pull my hair out!

Comment: You are welcome. Please be careful with the initial target of the event. If you place it too high, it could have performance implications. Try to get it as tight as you can.